# Time to break 256-bit AES key if 128-bit AES key could be broken in 20 years using brute force

Tags: aes

Lets say, a 128 bit AES key takes 20 years to break using brute force.
So now how do I calculate the time to break a 256-bit AES key by the same method from the given information?

I guess applying the unitary method to calculate for 256 is incorrect.

Comment: Multiply by `2^(256-128)`?

Comment: TL;DR, a bit more than a duodecillion years and a bit shy of 1e40 years.

Comment: @Ajedi32 how is that possible... you havent used the 20 years in the solution...for 128 bit key it takes 20 years. for 256 bit key how long does it take?

Comment: *Multiply* by `2^(256-128)`.

Comment: @Stephen Sorry i don't get the solution.
 Multiply by "what"???

Comment: @user162334: multiply by `2^128` the time it takes you to break 128-bit AES.  A quick mental calculation tells me that 20 years is about `2^4.3` years, so it should take about `2^(128 + 4.3) = 2^132.3` years.  A.k.a. too many years to bother with base 10 conversion.

Comment: 20*2^128 = 6805647338418769269267492148635364229120 years. The sun will swallow earth in roughly 5000000000 years.